# Why are some .desktop files prefixed with "org.kde." or "org.gnome."?

Tags: gnome, kde, .desktop

OS: Kubuntu 18.04

```
ls /usr/share/applications
apport-kde-mime.desktop           okularApplication_chm.desktop            org.kde.kmail2.desktop
boot-repair.desktop               okularApplication_comicbook.desktop      org.kde.kmenuedit.desktop
cantata.desktop                   okularApplication_djvu.desktop           org.kde.kmouth.desktop
debian-uxterm.desktop             okularApplication_dvi.desktop            org.kde.knetattach.desktop
debian-xterm.desktop              okularApplication_epub.desktop           org.kde.knotes.desktop
featherpad.desktop                okularApplication_fax.desktop            org.kde.kolourpaint.desktop
geany.desktop                     okularApplication_fb.desktop             org.kde.konsole.desktop
geoclue-where-am-i.desktop        okularApplication_ghostview.desktop      org.kde.kontact.desktop
google-chrome.desktop             okularApplication_kimgio.desktop         org.kde.konversation.desktop
gpaint.desktop                    okularApplication_md.desktop             org.kde.korganizer.desktop
guidus.desktop                    okularApplication_mobi.desktop           org.kde.krdc.desktop
guvcview.desktop                  okularApplication_ooo.desktop            org.kde.krita.desktop
hplj1020.desktop                  okularApplication_pdf.desktop            org.kde.ksudoku.desktop
im-config.desktop                 okularApplication_plucker.desktop        org.kde.ksysguard.desktop
kaddressbook-importer.desktop     okularApplication_tiff.desktop           org.kde.ksystemlog.desktop
kde4                              okularApplication_txt.desktop            org.kde.ktnef.desktop
kdesystemsettings.desktop         okularApplication_xps.desktop            org.kde.ktorrent.desktop
kleopatra_import.desktop          org.gnome.Screenshot.desktop             org.kde.kwalletmanager5.desktop
kmail_view.desktop                org.kde.accountwizard.desktop            org.kde.mboximporter.desktop
```

As can be seen, some applications available as part of the Kubuntu install have simple names such as `cantata.desktop` and `kmail_view.desktop`. Others have the `org.kde.` prefix: `org.kde.konsole.desktop` and `org.kde.ktorrent.desktop`.

There are also gtk applications such as  `org.gnome.Screenshot.desktop`, `gpaint.desktop` and `geany.desktop`  which I installed later.

So what is the significance of `org.gnome.` and `org.kde.` in `.desktop` filenames?

Comment: I think this might be to match their names in the AppStream database. Try `appstreamcli get org.kde.accountwizard.desktop` or `appstreamcli get org.gnome.Screenshot.desktop`

Comment: @muru it would be great if you write your comment as answer. Also consider to add commands like  `dpkg -S /usr/share/applications/org.*` to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Desktop Entry Specification**
https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/

> File naming
>
> The name of the desktop entry should follow the "reverse DNS"
>   convention: it should start with a reversed DNS domain name controlled
>   by the author of the application, in lower case. The domain name
>   should be followed by the name of the application, which is
>   conventionally written with words run together and initial capital
>   letters (CamelCase). For example, if the owner of example.org writes
>   "Foo Viewer", they might choose the name org.example.FooViewer,
>   resulting in a file named org.example.FooViewer.desktop.

**Example**

Dolphin KDE file manager had desktop file: 'dolphin.desktop' but with the 2014-10-07 commit - Convert to reverse dns https://cgit.kde.org/dolphin.git/commit/?id=a705337fab20e230a3f990624f5f7de3b2468b3f

the desktop file was renamed:

> src/org.kde.dolphin.desktop (renamed from src/dolphin.desktop)

**About freedesktop standards**

freedesktop.org: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/

> freedesktop.org is not a formal standards organization, though some
>   see a need for one that covers some of the areas we are working on.
>   For Linux operating system standards, look at the Linux Standard Base
>   project. The X.Org Foundation and the IETF are other groups that do
>   formal standards. The Free Standards Group is one group that publishes
>   "de jure" standards for free software; freedesktop.org is loosely
>   affiliated with the FSG.
>
> Unlike a standards organization, freedesktop.org is a "collaboration
>   zone" where ideas and code are tossed around, and de facto
>   specifications are encouraged.

Comment: Similarly for `gnome-screenshot`: https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-screenshot/commit/5b214f314f478542ea48a5ad4be71f38b6315d7d#diff-0565c171b00f25bcce912977eb8376e7